# Using jQuery to Fade in Transparent PNGs in IE7/8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, png, opacity

I have been observing that when using jQuery's fadeIn() function on PNGs with transparency, the transparency is disabled in IE7/8 for the duration of the animation. My research indicates that this is due to the fact that only one "filter" can be active on a given element, and both transparency and opacity are considered filters.

I have seen a few supposed solutions to this both on SO and elsewhere, but I have not had any success with any of them. I've tried things like wrapping the image in another element and fading that element. I've tried making the image a background image. Are there any tested/confirmed solutions or best practices for addressing this issue? I supposed I could just do some browser sniffing and use show() instead for IE, but I'd like to get the fades working if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

A fix I heard a lot about (never tried it myself though) is to fade a parent container holding the png image. Simply add a wrapper div with an id (or class) around the image and fade that one.

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <img src="image.png" />
</div>
```

If that doesn't do the trick you can try to set the image as a transparent background image and to fade the wrapper:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="image">
  </div>
</div>


#image
{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:transparent url('image.png') no-repeat;

  /* css For IE background image*/
  background:none\9;
  filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src="image.png", sizingMethod="crop");
}
```

note: the "\9" after the background for IE adresses only IE8 or below

Give it a try, IF it still won't work, try to render the png as png8 (not as png24)

Comment: I had tried putting the images in wrapper divs. IE8 actually just shows the image suddenly with no transition, which I suppose would be okay, but IE7 still has some weird artifacts. I didn't have any success with the background image method. What would using png8 do?

Comment: png-8 has a different image encoder than png-24. IE has always been better in decoding the transparence of a png-8 image. The png-8 only supports up to 256 colors (like a GIF image), a png-24 image supports millions of colors. So if you're not losing any quality (or if your image is accectable) you can try with png-8 instead of 24.

Comment: I don't think png-8 is going to work, since we have a lot of overlapping images, and the quality just isn't quite there. I might just write some new fade functions that do some browser detection, and for IE7/8, it calls show() instead of fadeIn().

Comment: Maybe that's the best way :) You don't even have to write your own function: since you're working with jQuery, you can use "$.browser.msie;" (returns true if IE) and jQuery.browser.version.
Explained here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

Comment: the fix you didnt tried - the "**add a wrapper div...around the image and fade that one**" - it fixes the unwanted black background, **BUT** you lose the fadeIn/Out effect... However I think it still looks better without black.